# Query list of tables using join between dba_tables and all_dependencies in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have around 15000 tables in my oracle database. I want to primarily fetch list of such tables which are not in use, considering they are not appearing in all_dependencies by using join between dba_tables and all_dependencies.

What would be the query?

Comment: you want the table that does not exists in all_dependencies ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that's what you want , tables that does not exists in all_dependencies

```
select  t.table_name from all_tables t where t.table_name
 not in (select referenced_name from all_dependencies d where t.table_name=d.referenced_name and d.REFERENCED_TYPE='TABLE')
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I want list of tables from DBA_TABLES which are not reflecting  in REFERENCED_NAME column of all_dependencies.

Comment: not reflecting as it doesnt exists ? the above query wont work for you ? what is missing in it

Answer (score 0):

```
Check this if it works for you..

SELECT *
  FROM dba_tables tb
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
              (SELECT 1
                 FROM all_dependencies dep
                WHERE     TB.OWNER = DEP.OWNER
                      AND TB.TABLE_NAME = DEP.REFERENCED_NAME
                      AND DEP.REFERENCED_TYPE = 'TABLE');
```

Answer (score 0):

The query becomes like:

```
SELECT t.table_name
  FROM dba_tables t
 WHERE t.table_name NOT IN (SELECT d.referenced_name 
                              FROM dba_dependencies d
                             WHERE d.REFERENCED_TYPE = 'TABLE'
                             and d.referenced_name =  t.table_name)
```